# Grails package-plugin exclude jar file

Tags: grails, plugins, jar, package

All,

I have created a plugin that I will be using across several projects. For testing purposes, I have included the jar file needed to connect to Oracle to test the domain classes in this plugin. I do not want this jar file to be included in the packaged plugin (done by running package-plugin). The jar file exists in the /lib directory. What do I have to do to make sure it gets excluded in the packaged plugin?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pluginExcludes` like [this](http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-ui-performance/tags/RELEASE_1_2_1/UiPerformanceGrailsPlugin.groovy):

```
class UiPerformanceGrailsPlugin {

    String version = '1.2.1'
    String grailsVersion = '1.0 > *'
    Map dependsOn = [:]
    List pluginExcludes = [
        'lib/build/*.jar',
        'lib/easymock.jar',
        'src/groovy/com/studentsonly/grails/plugins/uiperformance/taglib/AbstractTaglibTest.groovy'
    ]
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include the jar via maven instead you can in the build config set the export to false.

Comment: I know this is technically a seperate question, however, how do I do that?

Comment: I actually got this to work because I already have a maven repo i created, however the question was for a file in the /lib directory.

Comment: If there's an actual file in your lib folder, I think the only way is to erase it from the war is by hooking in the war generation and deleting it before it is packaged.

Put this in your BuildConfig.groovy:

grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
  delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/name_of_the_file.jar")
}